# How to name test runs according to project file

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have an Azure Pipelines step that runs tests like this:

```
      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        inputs:
          command: 'test'
          projects: src/Common/**/*Tests.*proj
          arguments: '-c Release'
```

This seems to give very unhelpful test run names, as you can see in the list below (apparently one test run per project that matches the glob pattern). Is there any way I can specify test run names so that each run is named after the project that is run (or otherwise more helpful than this), without having to have one step per project to be tested?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that by using the `testRunTitle` parameter, I can at least get some of the way:

```
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: 'test'
      testRunTitle: Libraries
      projects: src/Common/**/*Tests.*proj
      arguments: '-c Release'
```

This will name the test runs `Libraries_1`, `Libraries_2`, etc. as shown in the list below. I do not consider this a solution to the problem since it's still unclear which project the tests come from, and they are also sorted weirdly (neither alphabetically nor by `dotnet test` invocation), but if you have multiple `dotnet test` invocations like I have (not mentioned in the original question), it's at least better.

[image]